# How to make a backup from internal storage of my Galaxy S3 Neo while it stucks on Samsung logo screen?

Tags: samsung, boot

My Galaxy S3 Neo has stopped working without any clear reason! I woke up and looked at my phone screen. It was showing the logo of Samsung. Then I turned it off by removing the battery. Since then I have been trying to turn it on but again it stuck on the logo screen. I tried first, "wipe cache partition" from recovery menu (by pressing power bottom+home+volume up) but it did not work. Second, I tried using another battery and it shows that the battery works well. Third, I start using the safe mode but it could be loaded. There I have two questions:

1. I do not want to miss my personal information, photos, apps, etc. which are in my internal storage. This is very important for me. Please help me:(
2. What should I do with the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you have tried enough booting and it won't boot than all feasible option you have are

- look if only flashing system partition is possible and if it doesnt remove your data
- or if it is possible to root without loss of data, if possible do so and install recovery and extract your data to PC and reflash the firmware

Comment: thank you for your answer. Can you suggest a link which includes more information about the solutions you offered, please?

Comment: Will try to find if i can and post back here else you will have to Google it